# intellisense not working on remote jupyter connections

Tags: visual-studio-code

when I work on my local computer everything was expected. when I define a variable or hover over one, vs code recognizes the object correctly. I can also shift-click to see additional information.

When I use the ssh plugin and edit a text file remotely -> everything works fine.
when I work in a jupyter notebook locally -> everything works fine.

When I connect to a remote jupyter server (that is already running) -> IntelliSense does not work. I just recently set vs-code up, so everything should be on its default values.

Comment: Your tags are ambiguous. You either use VSCode or JupyterLab. If this question is not related to JupyterLab please remove this tag.

Comment: its related to the jupyter lab plugin in vs-code

Comment: There is no "jupyter lab" plugin for "vs-code". You are confusing [JupyterLab the application](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with [Jupyter the standard created by the Jupyter project](https://jupyter.org/). The plugin for VSCode merely provides an implementation of Jupyter interactive computing standards (like `.ipynb` file format). It has no shared codebase with JupyterLab AFAIK.

Comment: please focus on my initial question. thanks

Answer (score 0):

See response in the below issue. Sounds like this isn't supported on the stable release yet, but is working on the insiders branch.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/8628